# What is the best alternative to BatchStatement execute for retriving values from database (MSSQL 2008)

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a SQL query as shown below.

```
SELECT O_DEF,O_DATE,O_MOD from OBL_DEFINITVE WHERE OBL_DEFINITVE_ID =?
```

A collection of Ids is passed to this query and ran as Batch query. This executes for 10000 
times for retriveing values from Database.(Some one else mess)

```
public static Map getOBLDefinitionsAsMap(Collection oblIDs)
        throws java.sql.SQLException
    {
        Map retVal = new HashMap();
        if (oblIDs != null && (!oblIDs.isEmpty()))
        {
            BatchStatementObject stmt = new BatchStatementObject();
            stmt.setSql(SELECT O_DEF,O_DATE,O_MOD from OBL_DEFINITVE WHERE OBL_DEFINITVE_ID=?);
            stmt.setParameters(
                    PWMUtils.convertCollectionToSubLists(taskIDs, 1));        
            stmt.setResultsAsArray(true);
            QueryResults rows = stmt.executeBatchSelect();
            int rowSize = rows.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++)
            {
                QueryResults.Row aRow = (QueryResults.Row) rows.getRow(i);
                CoblDefinition ctd = new CoblDefinition(aRow);


                retVal.put(aRow.getLong(0), ctd);
            }
        }

        return retVal;
```

Now we had identified that if the query is modified to
add as

```
SELECT O_DEF,O_DATE,O_MOD from OBL_DEFINITVE WHERE OBL_DEFINITVE_ID in (???)
```

so that we can reduce it to 1 query.

The problem here is MSSQL server is throwing exception that

```
 Prepared or callable statement has more than 2000 parameter
```

And were struck here . Can some one provide any better alternative to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum number of allowed parameters, let's call it n. You can do one of the following:

- If you have m*n + k parameters, you can create m batches (or m+1 batches, if k is not 0). If you have 10000 parameters and 2000 is the maximum allowed parameters, you will only need 5 batches.
- Another solution is to generate the query string in your application and adding your parameters as string. This way you will run your query only once. This is an obvious optimization in speed, but you'll have a query string generated in your application. You would set your where clause like this:

String myWhereClause = "where TaskID = " + taskIDs[0];

for (int i = 1; i <  numberOfTaskIDs; i++)

{

```
myWhereClause += " or TaskID = " + taskIDs[i];
```

}

Comment: good idea..can u elaborate  a little more using above code.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using your own wrapper around PreparedStatement and addBatch(). You are clearly reaching a limit of how many statements/parameters can be batched at once. You will need to use executeBatch (eg every 100 or 1000) statements, instead of having it build up until the limit is reached.

**Edit:** Based on the comment below I reread the problem. The solution: make sure you use less than 2000 parameters when building the query. If necessary, breaking it up in two or more queries as required.

Comment: I do not want to use batch . Because it is running 10000 times.Instead use a Statement Object with     'in' clause with a fixed set of params.